# Clearing terminal in Linux with C++ code

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

Okay, I have been researching on how to do this, but say I am running a program that has a whole bit of output on the terminal, how would I clear the screen from within my program so that I can keep my program running?

I know I can just type `clear` in terminal and it clears it fine, but like I said, for this program it would be more beneficial for me.

I found something that works, however, I'm not sure what it is or what it is doing.

```
cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H";
```

That works but I have no clue what it is, if you could explain it, than I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

These are ANSI escape codes. The first one (`\033[2J`) clears the entire screen (`J`) from top to bottom (`2`). The second code (`\033[1;1H`) positions the cursor at row `1`, column `1`.

All ANSI escapes begin with the sequence <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>, have zero or more parameters delimited by <kbd>;</kbd>, and end with a command letter (<kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>H</kbd> in your case). `\033` is the C-style octal sequence for the escape character.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for the full roadshow.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of depending on specific escape sequences that may break in unexpected situations (though accepting that trade-off is fine, if it's what you want), you can just do the same thing you'd do at your shell:

```
std::system("clear");
```

Though generally system() is to be avoided, for a user-interactive program neither the extra shell parsing nor process overhead is significant.  There's no problem with shell escaping either, in this case.

You could always fork/exec to call clear if you did want to avoid system().  If you're already using [n]curses or another terminal library, use that.

Comment: TERM environment variable not set.

Comment: Note that in C++, you need to `#include <cstdlib>` to use std::system. Also, although "clear" works on bash, for a Windows command line, you need "cls".

Comment: system() will fork(), then start a bash and then run the command. 1) You must avoid system() and 2) this doesn't answer the question where it was asked for C++ code and not about running a system's command.

Comment: not portable anyway, clear does exactly same thing. You may  not have access to clear in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

For portability you should get the string from termcap's cl (clear) capability (Clear screen and cursor home). (Or use std::system("clear") as told by Roger Pate).

man 3 termcap (in ncurses)
man 5 termcap
set | grep TERMCAP

Comment: I am not able to understand it can you explain me?

Answer (score 1):

you can write in a terminal "clear > data" and read in data the escapes sequance

0x1B[H0x1B[2J0x1B[3J

so

```
std::cout << "\033[H\033[2J\033[3J" ;
```