# Linux console ; CLS not found error

Tags: c, console, system, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to compile a C project that I wrote while I used windows. I am trying to compile same project with same IDE (**Code::Blocks**) in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04). I have several `System("CLS")` functions used in my program. But the linux console says
`sh: 1:CLS: not found

Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
I have included `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>` (and several of course).

Comment: If you want your code to be portable, you can't call arbitrary system commands that may or may not exist on any particular system. In fact, you shouldn't assume the system has a screen until you check if it does. What would "CLS" do if you're talking to a line printer or text-to-speech engine? What would it do if your output was redirected to a file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that the command CLS does only exist on Windows. For Linux, the command you want is: `clear`.

Anyway, that will only partially solve the problem: a) you'll have the same problem if you port your program to a windows machine, and b) there is no reason for that to produce a segmentation fault.

Comment: Wow.. Call it the Mandela effect but I was sure years before I used `cls` // `clr` I always had it in my head dos etc was more verbose .. Even got me here to realise otherwise. Thanks?

Answer (score 4):

The `system` command runs shell commands on your local system.  `cls` is a valid DOS/Windows command, but it does not exist on Linux.  The `clear` command on Linux provides similar functionality.

The segmentation fault suggests you are not correctly handling the error.

Answer (score 0):

CLS is an old MS-DOS command not likely to be found on your Linux machine. You should not rely on spawning another process to clear your console text for you. You can call out to `clear` or [use ANSI escape codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062045/clearing-terminal-in-linux-with-c-code) to do the work for you. Neither are portable, but both are seen in wide use.