# Clean the screen in C

Tags: c++, c

I want to clean the Console screen every 2 seconds, so I tried to use the following command:`system("clear");` but it doesn't clear the screen. also the eclipse does not recognized the file "conio.h" for clrscr() function. I'm using Ubuntu OS. Any suggestions?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062045/clearing-terminal-in-linux-with-c-code

Comment: What does `system("clear");` do? What happens when you type `clear` at the command line? (And why do you want to clear the screen every 2 seconds?)

Comment: On Ubuntu, `/usr/bin/clear` is part of the `ncurses-bin` package; is it installed?

Comment: I'm noticing a lot of your questions have to do with shell-like procedures in C. Is there any reason you've chosen C to accomplish these tasks instead of a shell scripting language (like bash) or at least a higher level language that would make this easier (python or ruby) ?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered before: [How do you clear console screen in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347770/how-do-you-clear-console-screen-in-c)

Basically, it's not cross-platform. If you're using Ubuntu, this line should work:

```
printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
```

When the test is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
    printf("3\n");
    sleep(1);

    printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
    printf("2\n");
    sleep(1);

    printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
    printf("1\n");
    sleep(1);

    printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
    printf("0\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tried this. it's doesn't work. only print some gibberish

Comment: Are you running your program in bash? I just tested it and it worked. I'm on Linux Mint, it's based on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm running the program both in Terminal and Eclipse. note that this program is in the child process

Comment: It should work. Check my edit.