# Is there any function in iostream which allows clear screen in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to know whether iostream contain any function to clear the screen in C++ programming?

Comment: No it doesn't. C++ I/O is *abstract* and doesn't contain any concept of a screen.

Comment: Are you running the program in a terminal? What OS are you using? If Unix, you may be able to use the magic that is [ANSI codes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4062045/2602718).