# Is there an alternative to the 'system()' command in C++.?

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system, system

I have read a lot of answers saying that the `system()` command is bad. First off, why is it so bad? Second off, is there an alternative that doesn't produce such a security hole? I mostly want to know if there is a way to clear screen in C++. In python I have a clear function that checks the os name and runs either `system('cls')` or `system('clear')`. Is this a security hole as well? If so, is there a python alternative?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issuing system commands in Linux from C, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622693/issuing-system-commands-in-linux-from-c-c)

Comment: Handy reading: [Why should the system() function be avoided in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913446/why-should-the-system-function-be-avoided-in-c-and-c)

Comment: If you're only looking to clear the terminal and you're on a UNIX system, you can use ANSI escape codes and avoid calling another program entirely. See [Clearing terminal in Linux with C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4062045/2602718)

Comment: No, I am on a Windows 10 home os.

Comment: You probably should not use system("cls") to clear the console.

Comment: Search [softwarerecs.se] for a cursor positioning library.  Many of those have functions to clear the console.

Comment: Does the `\033[2J` not work on Windows?

Comment: Why this isn't built into C++: C++ is a very big tent with support for a staggering array of hardware and operating systems, and not all of them have a clearable console. Or much of a console, for that matter. Mandating that implementers add in support for clearing a console they don't even have is seen as a bit of a <expletive deleted> move.

Comment: "*I mostly want to know if there is a way to clear screen in C++*" - for Windows, see [Clearing the Screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/clearing-the-screen) on MSDN for an alternative that doesn't involve using `system("clr")`.

Comment: I believe you mean `system("cls")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system` functions (across many language, including Python and C++) are not inherently "bad" but they present difficulties for correct use.

## Security

You need to be absolutely sure that whatever you're executing via `system` is secure.

If you write `system("echo hello " + name)` then you need to be absolutely sure that `name` cannot be controlled by a malicious user.  `name = "; rm -rf /"` would result in `echo hello ; rm -rf /`, so if that's coming from a user, via something like a web form or a database, then you need to exercise a lot of caution, and I would recommend a more sophisticated solution than `system`.

A call like `system("clear")` is secure for your purposes.

## Usability

System calls give you several outputs (I'll give an example for calls to a `bash` shell):

- status code (whether the shell indicated an error condition)
- contents of STDOUT
- contents of STDERR

`system` returns the status code.  For commands like `ls`, you are interested in receiving STDOUT, and you may also check the status code.  This is unwieldy with `system`.

The Python `subprocess` module is generally accepted by the community as an easier way to manage these concerns.

## How to manage the console

If you're trying to manage the console display, you may be interested in a library like `ncurses` which has broad OS support.

Adding `ncurses` as a dependency could be heavy-handed, if clearing the screen is the only thing you need to do.  If that's the case, then I see nothing wrong with using `system()` like you're doing.

Comment: When I use the `system("cls");` command, the command prompt goes crazy, and just prints line after line and doesn't stop. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Actually, only when I use the Path variable for it. If I am in the workspace it works just fine. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @RedSox2, what is "when I use the Path variable for ti" supposed to mean in terms of running `system("cls")`? Which workspace works fine?

Comment: _@ajm_ _"If you write `system("echo hello " + name)"`_ Please note, that this won't be possible directly, supposed that `name` is of type `char*`. The command needs to be constructed either using a `std::string`, or `strcat()`.

Comment: In windows there is your `Path` variable which allows you to run .exe files quicker (e.g. you have to put the path to the min-GW bin in your path variable for it to work). So instead of navigation to the folder everytime I run command prompt, I can just type in `%foo%` if the file I want to run is foo.exe.

Answer (score 1):

> First off, why is it so bad?

Because you introduce dependencies to the OS in your code, and make it unportable.

> Second off, is there an alternative that doesn't produce such a security hole?

No, the existing alternatives (POSIX compatible) `fork()` and `execxx()` or `pipe()` have the same problems of introducing OS dependencies and security holes.

> Is this a security hole as well?

The main secuity hole is introduced with commands constructed from parameters like

```
void exec_ls(const std::string param) {
    std::string cmd;
    cmd = "ls -l " + param;
    system(cmd.c_str());
```

If someone manages to inject some additional command via `param`, e.g.

```
 std::string param = "dir ; rm -rf /*";
                       // ^^^^^^^^^^^
 exec_ls(param);
```

they can call all kinds of malicious commands.
Another security hole comes from the point, that someone might replace `cls` or `clear` commands on your system with some malicious code.
The only way to get over this, is to secure your system in a way, that such isn't possible.

> If so, is there a python alternative?

Using a different programming language as an intermediate caller doesn't fix the problem I mentioned above.

Comment: The security hole with `system` is that it runs the command via the shell, which is a *scripting language*. If you're just letting the user run an arbitrary command, that's fine. Whatever the result; it's their fault. But if you're allowing the user to supply arguments for a template command, it is completely your fault if you choose to run the command via `system`. That would be gross negligence.

Comment: @ErykSun Added a more realistic example than in the other answer, for that matter.