# Black square character improperly shown when rapidly printed

Tags: c++, output, unicode-literals

so i made this on repl.it :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<30; j++){
            for(int k=0; k<40; k++){
              cout<<"■"<<' ';
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        system("clear");
    }
}
```

### Issue

When i run the code, occasionally, exactly 2 characters right next to each other are replaced with the `�` character on mostly the lower half of the output.

### Tried:

Replacing the single quote for the space character after the square character with double quote,
moving the space character into the square character string:

Result: no observable changes.

Removing the space character:

Result: the issue still exists, but it occurs less frequently.

Reducing the amount `j` and `k` iterates:

Result: apparently the `�` characters no longer gets printed, but I doubt if the problem has really been solved (the probability of the issue occurring could have just been lowered to the point that I can't consistently reproduce the problem).

Comment: Did not reproduce on my machine.  Could be a bug with your terminal, especially if the UTF-8 sequence of the block character is being interrupted with other characters (such as control characters for terminal I/O).

Comment: According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) system will perform this function through a different thread using `popen`, is there a chance that this is not thread safe?

Comment: Although it says *"An explicit flush of std::cout is also necessary before a call to std::system, if the spawned process performs any screen I/O"* which you do ...

Comment: You should probably look into ncurses and adjacent libraries if you want to draw something. Calling `clear` several times per second will flicker your screen badly.

Comment: Instead of calling `clear` you can do the job yourself by printing a terminal sequence. That will clear up any buffering issues. Make sure to flush! [Clearing terminal in Linux with C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062045/clearing-terminal-in-linux-with-c-code)

Comment: @Botje >Make sure to flush!   But where should I flush, and do I use `cout.flush();` or do I append `<<flush` to the `cout` statements?

Comment: You should flush (both methods are fine) right after printing the escape sequence I linked to.

Comment: @Botje unfortunately it did not work for me, the result remained the same as the original code.

Comment: Are you still calling `clear` or are you printing the escape sequence for clearing?

Comment: @Botje i replaced the `system("clear");` with `cout<<"\033[2J\033[1;1H"<<flush;`

Comment: Out of ideas then, sorry.